# Which nuGet package for namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget-package, tfs-2015

I'd like to implement a server side plugin for TFS 2015, actually an event handler. I've found several examples which start with the general instruction like "Just implement the `ISubscriber` interface...". This should be in the namespace `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server`. But I am not able to find a nuGet package containing this interface. I've already installed almost all available TeamFoundation packages available. But to no avail.

Could somebody point me into the right direction, please?

Comment: The only way to get this assembly seems to be to copy it from the on-premises installation's bin folder. Weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.dll` from the Application Tier machine of TFS, which is supposed under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin`.

Comment: This answer doesn't please me, at all. But nevertheless, it seems to be correct. Sad enough...